# Crawler data from another website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-crawler

I using simplecrawler gem to get data from another website. It's easy and simple :). but this website require login to see all. please suggest me a solution to make it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Mechanize**](https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize/). But if you're scraping for spam, then may the fleas of a thousand camels infest your armpits.

Comment: Ahaha you're awesome! ))))